# Listview not appearing right away xamarin forms

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

The third or so page in my app contains a ListView, but the list for some reason doesn't display until I either toggle the view (which switches the views `ItemSource` to another list) or rotate the screen.

If I do the toggle twice (so back to the original starting state) the listview is there still. It seems like a bug but I haven't been able to find anything on it.

```
public partial class ReviewRequestsPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly List<RequestCell> closedRequestCells = new List<RequestCell>();
    private readonly List<RequestCell> openRequestCells = new List<RequestCell>();

    public ReviewRequestsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        BindingContext = new SvgImagesViewModels();
        new Footer().SetGestureRecognizers(null, Notifications, Help, Home, this);
        LoadRequestLists();
        ToggleSwitch.PropertyChanged += (o, ea) => { HandleToggle(((Switch) o).IsToggled); };
    }

    ....

    private void LoadRequestLists()
    {
        UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Loading Requests...", MaskType.Black);
        var client = new RestService().Client;
        var request =
            new RequestService().GetAllRequests();
        client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
        {
            var myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Request>>(response.Content, new DateTimeConverter());
            myList.ForEach(r =>
            {
                if (r.status.type == StatusType.CLOSED) closedRequestCells.Add(new RequestCell(r));
                else if (r.status.type != StatusType.DELETED) openRequestCells.Add(new RequestCell(r));
            });
            UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
            RequestsList.ItemSource = openRequestCells; 
        });
    }
    private void HandleToggle(bool isToggled)
    {
        Switchlabel.Text = isToggled ? Constants.Closed : Constants.Open;
        RequestsList.ItemsSource = isToggled ? closedRequestCells : openRequestCells;
    }
```

Is there something else I should be calling or doing so that the listview appears once I set the ItemSource? It doesn't make sense why it wouldn't be already though. Also nothing is failing and everything is working as expected, other than that

Answer (score 1):

The constructor does not set ItemsSource, at least not immediately.  It calls LoadRequestLists that starts an async Task which will eventually set ItemsSource, so at some point in the future, ItemsSource will be set (whenever the Rest response is received and the UI thread happens to run).

Since constructors cannot await an async Task, you will need to refactor your code so that the Rest client runs (and finishes) before the constructor, and so the ReviewRequestsPage will take in the List as a parameter. Then the constructor can build the openRequestCells and closedRequestCells and assign to ItemsSource.

Comment: Ok I see what your'e saying. But why would toggling the list make it appear? or rotating the screen? Also I changed my lists to `ObservableCollection` and now it works